# Некорректная работа функции ручного переключения аудиодорожки

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, disnake

Используемая библиотека disnake (от discord.py). Python.

Когда воспроизводятся аудиодорожки из очереди, ссылка на следующую дорожку автоматически вытягивается из очереди, благодаря параметру `after` функции `voice_client.play(after=...)`, но если попытаться по нажатию кнопки переключить трек, происходит переключение до самого конца списка очереди.

Подозреваю, что проблема может быть в использовании `after`, или функции `voice_client.stop()`.

```
async def next_track_callback(self, interaction: disnake.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.defer()
    print(f"next track b clicked    {datetime.datetime.now()}")
    await self.play_next()

async def play_next(self):


    self.voice_client.stop()

    if self.music_queue.__len__() > 0:
        print("retrieving next audio")
        track_name, url = self.music_queue[0]['title'], self.music_queue[0]['url']
        if self.embed.fields.__len__() == 0:
            self.embed.add_field(name="Playing now", value=track_name, inline=True)
        else:
            self.embed.set_field_at(index=0, name="Playing now", value=track_name, inline=True)

        self.music_queue.pop(0)
        print("after got link from queue= " + str(len(self.music_queue))+f"    [{datetime.datetime.now()}]")
        try:
            self.que_fetch()
            FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
                              'options': '-vn'}
            source = disnake.PCMVolumeTransformer(
                disnake.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=url, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS,
                                       executable=r"dependencies\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg.exe"))

            def play_next_callback():
                coro = self.play_next()

                future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, self.bot.loop)
                future.result()

            self.voice_client.play(source=source,after=lambda _: play_next_callback())
            self.is_playing = True

        except disnake.ClientException as e:
            print("player playing!: ", e)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    else:
        print("stopping!")
        self.embed.clear_fields()
        coro = self.stopall()
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro=coro, loop=self.bot.loop).result()
        return
```

```
DEBUG

retrieving next audio

after got link from queue= 3    [2023-08-31 18:52:15.211099]

correcting embed

correcting embed

next track b clicked    2023-08-31 18:52:52.497262

retrieving next audio

after got link from queue= 3    [2023-08-31 18:52:52.497262]

correcting embed

retrieving next audio

after got link from queue= 2    [2023-08-31 18:52:52.517843]

correcting embed

retrieving next audio

after got link from queue= 1    [2023-08-31 18:52:52.540436]

correcting embed
retrieving next audio

after got link from queue= 0    [2023-08-31 18:52:53.118375]

correcting embed

stopping!
```

Каждая аудиодорожка по длине не менее 3х минут.

Работа кнопки описана в `next_track_callback`, переключение треков, работа очереди - в `play_next`.

Помогите решить проблему, критически важно. Если я что-либо упустил, дайте мне знать.